# Android - Best Practice for using a common WebView client

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I'm creating an app where there are `WebView`s in many different activities. But all the WebViews use the same `WebViewClient`. Currently I am creating a `new WebViewClient` for every `WebView` and using it. I wanted to know whats the best way of doing this. Is it a good idea to put a `static final WebViewClient` object at the Application level and use it for each `WebView` or is there any other better/right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not make a static WebViewClient as all your activities' WebViews need their own instantiation of the object and making it static could cause problems.

What  you're doing is fine.  However, if all of your WebViewClient definitions do exactly the same thing, you may want to think about defining it once in a separate class by extending WebViewClient and overriding the methods that you need.  Then assing your custom webViewClient to your webviews in each of your activities.

Comment: what kind of problems could arise by making it static?

Comment: In a scenario where you have multiple webviews in a single activity, there might be issues with the webveiws trying to reference the client at the same time.  Since you're not doing that, give it a shot.  What have you got to lose?  Extend your application and put it in there.

Comment: There are different WebViewClients which one in is the most powerful and lightweight? Most of them are really slow in loading page contents and response to user interactions with the contents.